# Android-NDK Project Eclipse build error

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk

I have an Android project with native code. When I make a checkout from my repo and build the clean version it builds ok and starts on the device, but after I run `project->clean` eclipse command I got an error:

```
...
Install        : libgnustl_shared.so => libs/armeabi/libgnustl_shared.so

D:/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip: unable to rename './libs/armeabi/libgnustl_shared.so'; reason: File exists
make: *** [libs/armeabi/libgnustl_shared.so] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file `libs/armeabi/libgnustl_shared.so'

**** Build Finished ****
```

This error can be reproduced in the Cygwin console with the same output (Yes, I'm working under MS Windows Vista).

I've got the same error when I was initializing the project. And it was solved by putting the `libgnustl_shared.so` file into `obj/local/armeabi/libgnustl_shared.so` and setting the 777 rights to all project files through the cygwin console running under administrator. But now this doesn't help.

You can find my project on the github 
https://github.com/aboritskiy/pacman
I haven't setup any project license yet, and I hope I'm not violating any other project licenses with this educational project.

The JNI-enabled functionality is in the `jni-powered` branch.

**EDIT:**
It seems like I'm including the `libgnustl_shared.so` in wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

You've got `https://github.com/aboritskiy/pacman/blob/jni-powered/libs/armeabi/libgnustl_shared.so` in your repository, but NDK thinks that it should be created during build.

Comment: Hmmm, ok! Where is the misconfiguration?

Comment: This file should not be part of your version control.

Comment: It is not an issue of version control, because even if I delete both `./obj` and `./libs` from the project it stil compiles with the same error.

Comment: It is really strange that project can compile successfully from time-to-time, as there are some timing issues during file IO.

Comment: try this scenario:  make a clean checkout,  delete `./libs` and `./obj`,  build project,  it should build ok in last version, then build again and here the error should appear. I have the same version of NDK

Comment: Probably the mistake is that you set `./obj` and `./libs` as output paths in Eclipse. I have never touched these settings for NDK projects. The effect of this setting seems to be that Eclipse can "scrub these folders when cleaning projects". It is not clear how this _scrub_ syncs with `ndk-build` which uses, in terms of Eclipse, an external makefile. Please verify if your problem can be reproduced from Windows command line (`cd pacman-jni-powered` and `ndk-build`).

Comment: It is a bit stupid but the problem doesn't appear any more...  I only edited the Android.mk, I added the `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/` line. And it was done yesterday and there wasn't any effect, may be restarting the eclipse lead to this effect...

Comment: Restarting eclipse should have been the first thing to try!

Comment: Alex, would You mind If I accept the summarized answer? Or change your own answer, that I could accept it.

Comment: I believe you are wrong: `ndk-build` does take care of `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` for me. I will check and post a detailed reply.

Answer (score 1):

I observed this issue when I have Tortoise Git installed and TGitCache.exe is running in the background, and also the code which I am building is repository code.

Try killing TGitCache.exe in task manager and re-build.

Answer (score 0):

**Summarizing:**

I wanted to add the `libgnustl_shared.so` to the project. I was using the Eclipse with Android Developer Tools plugin and Android Native Developer Tools plugin. But I had complation error, this error could be reproduced through eclipse and through the Cygwin console.

The problem was in misconfiguration of `Android.mk`: to include `libgnustl_shared.so` I have to add

1. `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/`
   to `Android.mk`,
2. `APP_STL := gnustl_shared`  to the `Application.mk` file.

But initially I had only the second option.

Great thanks to **Alex Cohn** for useful advices during this debug.

Comment: It's final: with **r8b**, you don't need to manually set `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` to point to the appropriate **libstd** `include` directory. You have another mistake in your `Android.mk` file which, if you are unlucky, may cause many troubles: you don't need `-L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib` in your `LOCAL_LDLIBS`. `ndk-build` will add all necessary library paths based on platform, `APP_STL`, and other parameters.