# Inconsistent file sizes when generating a signed APK for an NDK app in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I have been having difficulty generating valid APKs in Eclipse for an NDK app I am developing. The file sizes are very inconsistent. To generate the APK, I am clicking on my project and going to:

```
Tools --> Export Signed Application Package...
```

I am using Eclipse Juno SR 2, Android NDK r9 and ADT 22.3 (not the ADT bundle version of Eclipse).

After generating the APK several times and following the signing process, I received the following file sizes:

```
 5268198 app1.apk
12388155 app2.apk
 6092599 app3.apk
12320133 app4.apk
12201439 app5.apk
```

Note that I made no changes to any files in the project (or files that the project is dependent upon) in between these 'runs'.

Note also that some of these work when deployed to my phone and others do not. It is very hit and miss!

Upon renaming these to `.zip` files and checking their contents, it is the size of the lib file generated by the NDK run that is to blame it seems. In `app1.apk` it is 1,584kb (uncompressed) and in `app2.apk` it is 14,892kb. There is a symbol stripping process as part of the NDK build so I assumed that this was the problem since it would account for the variation in lib sizes. In fact, upon closer inspection of the signed APK generation process, I noticed that the larger APKs typically had the following output in the NDK console:

```
C:/Android/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded ./libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative.so
C:/Android/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip: unable to rename './libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative.so'; reason: File exists
make: *** [libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative.so] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file 'libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative.so'
make: unlink: libs/armeabi-v7a/libnative.so: Permission denied
```

My theory was that while the NDK build is taking place, perhaps another part of the Makefile is accessing the lib file or accessing it as soon as it is created (and not yet stripped). This interference is leading to the variation in APK sizes.

On a whim, I tried switching off 'Build Automatically' in Eclipse and this did the trick in that I can now generate APKs and they have a consistent size. Presumably Eclipse/CDT does not have enough 'knowledge' of the NDK build script to hold off automatically invoking the NDK build while the NDK build is already in process!

I shouldn't have to switch this option off though, should I? Is this a bug? Are other people seeing this behaviour? Colleagues of mine using the ADT bundle version of Eclipse don't have this issue.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Note that this question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/13943563/249239 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/13549772/249239 in that the workaround may be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.cproject` file. You would expect something like

```
<storageModule moduleId="refreshScope" versionNumber="1">
    <resource resourceType="PROJECT" workspacePath="/MainActivity"/>
</storageModule>
```

Here, MainActivity is my project name. Yours will be different.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have: `<storageModule moduleId="refreshScope" versionNumber="1">
      <resource resourceType="PROJECT" workspacePath="/ProjectName"/>
    </storageModule>` where `ProjectName` is my project's name. Why should this lead to the effect I was seeing?